# Swift tap recognizer on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I have a table view that will get it's data from a social network API. the cell has 2 labels and an imageView inside of it and it has a custom class

```
import UIKit

class resultsCellController: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var resultImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var resultName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var resultBioOrUsername: UILabel!
 }
```

of course there are other functions but they're not important. 
What i want to do is the following:

1. The app gets the data from the api and loads the table

   When the user taps on a specific cell i want the text of one of the labels to be saved to a server.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //Code
    }`
but it doesn't seem in work because it doesn't have access to the cell itself since i have to put it in the class where the tableView is, not the cell Class.

Comment: please don't. just **don't optimize prematurely.** thanks.

Comment: Just use the type of variable that is appropriate for what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

By far your best bet is to stick with `Int` when you need an integer, and when you need a boolean value, use `Bool`.  Don’t start second-guessing about speed or memory usage.  The time you should worry about the size of a datatype is when you are storing a seriously big amount of data, and even then, only look into it after you’ve written something and are able to test it to verify it’s a problem.

Messing with sizes to optimize CPU usage is quite probably going to be counterproductive.  On a 64-bit CPU you could find using 32-bit integers makes performance worse, not better.  Or maybe not.  But if it is faster it’ll be a micro-optimization.  You’ll also find yourself fighting with the type system more – lots of standard Swift functions take `Int`s – you’ll be casting all over the place to wedge your non-standard sized types into them.

If you want to make your code fast, focus on two things.

First, make sure your algorithms are efficient in terms of complexity (for example, they don’t needlessly re-compute values in loops when they could compute them ahead of time).  Your `Int32` isn’t going to save you if you accidentally call an O(n) calculation within an O(n) loop.

Second, give the compiler as much room to optimize as possible.  Use value types (i.e. structs) when dealing with simple data types.  Favour static polymorphism (such as overloading and generics) rather than dynamic.  And use types for their meaning, not for what you think might be faster.

A `Bool` is actually smaller than an `Int32` (1 byte versus 4).  But this isn’t why you should use it – you should use it because it signals intent.  Signals it to the compiler, and signals it to you.  You can’t accidentally misinterpret a `Bool` as a number.  A slow program might be bad, but a program that behaves incorrectly or crashes is far worse.

Answer (score 0):

size of Bool variable is 1 byte. size of Int variable is 4 bytes. If you have thousands of variables, you can save some memory by using Bool (and even more memory by using bits). Probably both types will show the same performance on processor.

I suggest you to use the type which is more suitable for your task. If you need simple flag, Bool is fine and there's no need to use Int.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i meant. 1 bit in comparison to 4 bytes( 32bits).

Comment: Please note that Bool is 1 byte, not 1 bit.

Comment: How could it be 4 bits ? Isn't it either 0 or 1? I really want to know more about this topic

Comment: 1 byte is 8 bit (in almost all modern computers). 1 bit is used, 7 bits are wasted. That's the way operating memory and processor works. 1 byte is minimal addressable unit and using 1 bit for a variable could be tricky for a compiler. While it's theoretically possible for a compiler to use 1 byte to store several Bool variables, I highly doubt that it'll do it.